# Find all valid user mentions in text with regex

Tags: python, regex

I need to find all user mentions in comment. It means that I need to find all matches of regex `1)` where there are no more than one point and underscore after `@`.

Here is regex  that can be used to find all possible mentions:

1) `\B(@[a-z_.]{3,24})`

I want to be sure that symbols after `@` are valid username (don't need to check whether user exists in db)

I am using this regex to validate username:

2) `'^(?!(.*?\_){2})(?!(.*?\.){2})[a-z0-9\._]{3,24}$'`

It checks that username consists of 3-24 symbols and it contains 0-1 points and underscores.
Username regex will not work for the whole text because of `negative lookahead`

I tried to combine regex `1)` and `2)` but it will not work good.

[Currently I stopped here](https://regex101.com/r/ayUjyJ/2/)

Also it is possible to use regex `1)` and for each match use regex `2)`. I don't like it because it will work very slow on long comments...

*UPDATE*:
For examle I have a comment

`'text @valid_username text @unvalid_username_ text @valid.username text @unvalid..username'`

I need only those mentions where username constists of 3-24 symbols and don't contain more than one point and underscore

Comment: I'm sorry sir. I do not fully understand what you are trying to achieve. Could you please clarify your question? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Probably, https://regex101.com/r/ayUjyJ/3 will help, but it is not crystal clear what output you need..

Comment: @BlueRineS I have updated first lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may consider a good-enough pattern like

```
r'\B@(?!(?:[a-z0-9.]*_){2})(?!(?:[a-z0-9_]*\.){2})[._a-z0-9]{3,24}\b'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Hsc94r/1). The only drawback of the pattern is that if the valid mention can end with `.`, it will match up to that `.` (see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/Hsc94r/2)).

**Details**

- `\B@` - a `@` not preceded with a word char
- `(?!(?:[a-z0-9.]*_){2})` - no two `_` chars anywhere after `@`
- `(?!(?:[a-z0-9_]*\.){2})` - no two `.` chars anywhere after `@`
- `[._a-z0-9]{3,24}` - three to twenty-four letters, digits, `.` and `_`
- `\b` - word boundary

Note you may actually use [some Python code](https://ideone.com/3woAII) to filter your results obtained with `\B(@[a-z_.]{3,24})`:

```
import re
s = 'text @valid_username text @unvalid_username_ text @valid.username text @unvalid..username  @validusername.'
print([x for x in re.findall(r'\B@[._a-z0-9]{3,24}', s) if x.count('.') < 2 and x.count('_') < 2 ])
# => ['@valid_username', '@valid.username', '@validusername.']
```